# ignore imported file with istanbul

Tags: react-native, jestjs

due to deployment requirements, cant lower the coverage limits. I Have the following line

```
/* istanbul ignore file */
import SignatureCapture from 'react-native-signature-capture';
```

ignore file, ignore next don't work. the component itself is fully tested. SignatureCapture is the only imported library (apart from react and react-native) and it is reporting that IF and Else there are not covered, thus refusing deployment.

is there a way to ignore imported node modules from coverage?

Answer (score 0):

You need mock library `react-native-signature-capture`